# How to use globalizejs in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, jquery-globalize

Would anyone have an example of using globalizejs lib in Angular installation and usage?

I'm developing in Angular 4 with Angular-cli and devextreme

It is not very clear at devextreme about the use of globalizejs with angular

Answer (score 2):

There is examples repository on github [devextreme-examples](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-examples) with two projects about globalization: systemjs-angular-globalize and webpack-angular-globalize.